# Spring Boot + Thymeleaf: populating large dropdown

Tags: spring, list, spring-boot, thymeleaf, dropdown

I have a large List, which needs to be put into a drop-down menu.

```
<select class="form-control" required name="family" id="family" th:field="${succulent.family}">
    <option value="" selected="selected">---</option>
    <option th:each="family : ${families}" th:value="${family.id}" th:text="${family.name}"></option>
</select>
```

families has ~ 8000 entries.

My controller fetches the data fast enough, but loading of the template takes around 30 sec. if i comment the th:each out, the template is loaded instantly.

Any clues how to fix it? The only solution i can think of, is a autocomplete-field. But that wouldnt allow the user to see the dropdown.

Comment: Nobody will scroll drop-down list of 8000 entries. Use autocomplete. Show values by first 3-4 letters for example. So, you will narrow the list down to tens or hundreds entries.

Comment: @Alex but you can use a drop-down autocomplete and the user will keep seeing the dropdown, and won't have this problem, but that amount of data you need to use autocomplete